# Cannot set color for visited links in Email

Tags: html, css, email

This is a simple question that I'm having lots of trouble finding the answer to. I'm setting the color of links like so:

```
<a style="color:#3067b3;text-decoration:none;" href="#">colored link</a>
```

But when I click the link it turns white for no reason, and I have not been able to change it back. Does anybody know why this is?

NOTE: I am designing an email that is meant to look correct across different email clients. Otherwise I would be specifying styles in a CSS file.

Comment: are you looking at the link in a browser or an email or a document?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Stephen's solution did work for me. I can't comment yet, so here's the necessary code Rajneesh asked for:

```
<a href="http://www.example.org" style="text-decoration: none; color: #EC7405;">
    <strong style="text-decoration: none; color: #EC7405;">Example Link</strong>
</a>
```

Make sure to use <strong>, I tried it with a <span> first, but that didn't work, it needed to be a <strong> tag for some reason. Also make sure to add at least the "text-decoration: none" style to the <a>, otherwise there might appear an underline after the link was clicked. I used the sure solution and added the full style to both the <a> and the <strong>, better safe than sorry ;)

Comment: Could you please add if you need the color on the anchor tag as well as the strong tag and why?

Comment: If I didn't format the font on the anchor tag, the link would have an underline in the default link color (IIRC only in Outlook, but since that was the main target paltform for the layout, it had to be fixed). Probably removing the underline would work, too. But since I just had to add the same style attribute, I went for that.

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same issue and found that adding a strong tag around the link text prevents it from turning purple on click. If you dont want the link to be bold just add font-weight:normal to the strong tag

Comment: Is it only `<strong>` or do other inline tags such as `<span>` work?

Answer (score 9):

The best way from my experience is using standard body link and `vlink`, it does work in outlook

```html
<body link="#DD0000" vlink="#DD0000">
 <a href="#">Here</a>
  </body>
```

Comment: For some reason when HTML emails are sent to outlook 2016 (and possibly older versions) it inserts a <span> tag within <a> tags. This would be fine except it also copies any inline style from the <a> tag to the <span> Therefore:

<a style="color: red, text-decoration: none">Link</a>

becomes:

<a><span style="color: red, text-decoration: none">Link</span></a>

This answer solved my problem!

Answer (score 4):

Most Email clients will completely ignore any CSS thats not inline, so external stylesheets are not the way to go